# How to formulate this maximisation problem?

Tags: optimization, word-problem

**Question**

"A company offers the following schedule of charges: $30 per thousand for orders of 50,000 or less, with the charge decreased by 37.5 cents for each thousand above 50,000. Find the order size that makes th company's receipts a maximum".

**Attempted Answer**

I understand that I have to formulate the above in some function, say f(x) where x is the number of orders, and then differentiate the function and equate the derivative to 0 to identify any maximum point. Yet, I am stuck as to putting the above into an equation.

Some ideas that ran through my head included: 1) It's a linear equation where the gradient shifts after x= 50,000. 2) It requires two equations with different domains. Then I gave up.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Receipts obviously increase steadily for orders up to 50,000. So you can be sure your answer lies in the domain of orders higher than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the order size is $(50+N)$ thousand. Then the charge is \$ $30-0.375N$ per thousand.

The total charge is $(50+N)(30-0.375N)=1500+11.25N-0.375N^2$.

This has a maximum where (by differentiation) $11.25=0.75N$ i.e. $N=15$.

The required order is for $65$ thousand.

Comment: Perfect! Yes, the textbook only gives the answer (which is, as you show, 65,000). So the question is saying that 37.5 cents is removed from the initial price with each thousand orders. So, theoretically, after ordering 80,000 items, the company would start paying the customer (obviously a company wouldn't do that). Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of help.